# what regex match strings of characters before ":"

Tags: javascript, regex

Example of text:

```
Some string here : my value
Another string : my value
String : my value
```

I want to match everything before and including the symbol `:`

My wanted output is:

```
Some string here : 
Another string : 
String :
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't even need a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
(.* :)
```

See example: https://regex101.com/r/bA1cQ1/2

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regular expression, because [it's not a nail to regex's hammer](http://xkcd.com/478/).

```js
var strToMatch = "Some string here : my value";
var match = strToMatch.slice(0,strToMatch.indexOf(':')+1);

// do something with the match
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = match;
```